# Intermittent results when using .readline() on a console application

Tags: java

I have an external console app I am trying to read from. My code starts the .exe process. I am using a buffered reader, .getinputstream, and then .readLine. I then print the Line to the console. I have some unexpected results doing this.

1. after starting the Process i do not see it in my task manager processes. I used isAlive() to verify that the process has actually started and, it returns true. If I run the process in a separate java file, the process starts correctly. I can see it in task manager processes.

2)When running the code, I get intermittent results. Most of the time .println(Line) does not print anything(in the eclipse). I have seen the println work on this code a couple of times but, it is not constantly working.

I have only been writing in java for about two weeks, so my understanding of how most of these functions work is remedial. I feel like this is either a timing issue between the .exe and my code or i am using something for the wrong purpose as well as making some things harder than they have to be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Windows 10, Eclipse IDE

```
public class P3Data {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

try {
        //OutputStream r = P3d.getOutputStream();
        //PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(r);
    
        //System.out.println(ps.toString());
                
                if (Ignition().isAlive() ) {
                    String alive = new String("Tagged is on");
                    System.out.println("the program "+alive);
                }
        
         String line;
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Ignition().getInputStream()));
        {
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
              line = input.readLine();
                //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                System.out.println(line);
            //System.out.println("P3d running");
            }           
            
             input.close();
        }
                        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        
        
        
    }
            
  System.out.println("Program ended");
 }

public static Process Ignition() throws IOException{
            
             String appname = new String("Consoledata.exe");
             String Fname = new  String("C:\\Users\\...\"+ appname);
            
    String command[] = {Fname};  
    
    ProcessBuilder Prep =new ProcessBuilder(command);
    
    Process P3d = Prep.start();
   return P3d ;
    
}

}
```

Comment: You're starting a process in a loop - why? You seem to have confused yourself, which is the kind of thing that can happen of course when you make your methods names noun-based instead of verb-based. It should start lower case as well. `Process p = startProcess();` is the kind of thing that should be happening.

Comment: I edited my code to a more simple version. Can you explain " You're starting a process in a loop"? Is it trying to start a new Ignition() every time it reads the line in the While()?

Comment: Please follow what I suggested

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance. For Process to work properly it has to be lowercase "p"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove the extra ".readline". The code was writing a 0 length string on the second .readline leading me to believe i was not getting data. The solution was provided to me in this forum.

https://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/file-i-o-other-i-o-streams/43884-using-external-exe-input-stream.html#post172381